# $a_n =0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ if $\sum a_n^k =0$ for all integers $k \ge 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\sum a_n$ is an absolutely converging complex series and that for all integers $k \ge 1$, $\sum a_n^k =0$.

How to prove that the $a_n$ are all equal to $0$?

I was looking to extend Newton's identities to infinite number of variables, but I'm not able to write a simple proper proof!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume that the conclusion is wrong, and let $m$ be the smallest
index such that $a_m \ne 0$. Without loss of generality we can
assume that $m=1$, i.e.
$$ \tag 1
a_1 \ne 0 \, .
$$

Let $0 < \varepsilon <  \frac 12|a_1|$. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is absolutely convergent, therefore  there is an integer $N$ such that
$$
  \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |a_n| < \varepsilon \, .
$$
and in particular $|a_n| < \varepsilon$ for $n > N$. It follows that
for all integers $k$,
$$
  \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |a_n|^k \le \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \varepsilon^{k-1}|a_n| = \varepsilon^{k-1} \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |a_n| < \varepsilon^k \, .
$$

Since $\sum a_n^k =0$, the $k$-th power sums
$$
p_k := p_k(a_1, \ldots, a_N) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n^k
$$
satisfy
$$ \tag 2
  |p_k| =  \bigl| \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n^k \, \bigr| \le 
  \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |a_n|^k < \varepsilon^k
$$
for $1 \le k \le N$.

Now let
$$
e_k := e_k(a_1, \ldots, a_N) 
$$ be the $k$-th [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)
in the variables $a_1, \ldots, a_N$.

Then $e_0 = 1$, and [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) state that
$$
\begin{aligned}
 e_1 &= p_1 \\
 2e_2 &= e_1 p_1 - p_2 \\
 3e_3 &= e_2 p_1 - e_1 p_2 + p_3
\end{aligned}
$$
and generally
$$ \tag 3
 k e_k = \sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i-1} e_{k-i} p_i \, \text{ for } k \ge 0 \, .
$$

From $(2)$ and $(3)$ it follows easily by induction that 
the elementary symmetric polynomials satisfy
$$
  |e_k| \le \varepsilon^k \text{ for } 0 \le k \le N \, .
$$

Now define
$$
P(x) = (x-a_1)(x-a_2) \cdots (x-a_N) \\
= x^N - e_1 x^{N-1} + e_2 x^{N-2} \cdots \pm e_N \, .
$$
Then $P(a_1) = 0$ and therefore $r := |a_1|$ satisfies
$$
 r^N \le |e_1| r^{N-1} + |e_2| r^{N-2} + \cdots + |e_N| \\
 \le \varepsilon r^{N-1} + \varepsilon^2 r^{N-2} + \cdots + \varepsilon^N \\
 = \varepsilon r^{N-1} \bigl( 1 + \frac{\varepsilon}{r } + \cdots + 
(\frac{\varepsilon}{r })^{N-1} \bigr)
$$
or 
$$
1 \le \frac{\varepsilon}{r } \bigl( 1 + \frac{\varepsilon}{r } + \cdots + 
(\frac{\varepsilon}{r })^{N-1} \bigr) \, .
$$
$\varepsilon$ was chosen such that $0 < \frac \varepsilon r < \frac 12$, therefore
$$
1 < \frac 12 \bigl( 1 + \frac 12 + \cdots + 
(\frac 12)^{N-1} \bigr) < 1 
$$
which is a contradiction.

So the initial assumption is wrong, and it is proven that
all $a_n$ are zero.

Comment: Seems right. Bet it is in Polya and Szego.

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure if you also want to look at other proofs, but here is a complex-analytic proof anyway.

---

Define $f(z)$ by the following series

$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{1 - a_n z}. $$

Now we make the following claim.

> **Claim.** For $f(z)$ the followings are true:
>
> - $f(z)$ is holomorphic near $z = 0$.
> - $f(z)$ is meromoprhic on $\Bbb{C}$ and the termwise differentiation is applicable.

Assume first that this claim is true. Then notice that for any $k \geq 0$ we have

$$ f^{(k)}(0) = k! \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^{k+1} = 0. $$

This shows that $f(z) \equiv 0$ and in particular, $f(z)$ has no poles. On the other hand, if $a_m \neq 0$ for some $m$, then $f(z)$ should have a simple pole at $z = 1/a_m$. Indeed, we should have

$$ \underset{z=1/a_m}{\operatorname{Res}} f(z) = -(\# \{ n : a_n = a_m \}) \neq 0. $$

This contradiction implies that $a_n = 0$ for all $n$. ////

---

*Proof of Claim.* Both claims are easily verified if we prove the following claim: for any $R > 0$, there exists $N$ such that the tail sum

$$ T_{N}(z) := \sum_{n \geq N} \frac{a_n}{1-a_n z} $$

converges uniformly on $|z| \leq R$. Indeed, let $R > 0$ be arbitrary. Since $\sum |a_n| < \infty$, we can choose $N$ such that $|a_n|R \leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n \geq N$. Then on $|z| \leq R$

$$ \left| \frac{a_n}{1 - a_n z} \right| \leq 2|a_n|. $$

This proves that $T_N(z)$ converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M-test. ////

Comment: Very nice! I had tried to work with an infinite product, but didn't think of taking the logarithmic derivative.

Comment: Thanks Sangchul. You came to the proof by looking at a complex function series having the appropriate derivatives? Or was it another idea?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, Yes, I wanted to create a function so that (1) derivatives at $z = 0$ yield the sums $\sum_n a_n^k$ and (2) somehow $f(z)$ is capable of marking the position of $(a_n)$. In my first trial I attempted to use $f(z) = \sum_n (\exp(a_n z) - 1)$ but was not successful. Hopefully, my second choice worked.

Comment: @MartinR, Thank you! And I also like your proof as it seems to be generalized easily to other spaces.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net If you define $c_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^k=0$ and consider the power series $f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_kz^k$ then you get the function after changing the summation order and adding the geometric series.

Comment: @SangchulLee: Your approach could be applied to this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2675228/42969 as well ...

Comment: @MartinR, Oh yes, it seems so. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @SangchulLee: Did you see this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4641851/42969? It has now been asked if the same conclusion holds if $\sum a_n$ is only assumed to be *conditionally convergent.*

Comment: @MartinR, Thank you for the link! The question in the link seems quite challenging, and I can see that my approach breaks down in that case.

Comment: @SangchulLee: An indeed, the conclusion *fails* under the weaker assumption.

Comment: @MartinR, That's very interesting! I would definitely give it a read to the linked paper therein.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG assume that $r=\max_{n\ge 1}|a_n|<1$ (otherwise do scaling).
Define
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{z-a_n}.
$$

1. It converges uniformly absolutely to a bounded analytical function in $|z|\ge 1$ due to the estimate
   $$
   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{|z-a_n|}\le 
   \frac{1}{1-r}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|<+\infty.
   $$
2. Inside the unit disc the Cauchy integral gives
   $$
   \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}z^{k-1}f(z)\,dz=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^k=0,\quad\forall k\ge 1.
   $$
3. Hence (a slight modification to include $n=0$ of) [F. and M. Riesz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F._and_M._Riesz_theorem) implies that $f\in H_0^1$, that is, $f$ is analytical inside the disc and $f(0)=0$.
4. Finally, [Liouville theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) makes $f\equiv 0$ and, thus, all $a_n=0$.