# If for any $k$, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n^k=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_n^k$, then$(a_n)=(b_{σ(n)}),\ σ \in{\mathfrak S}_{\mathbb N}$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, summation-by-parts

Let $(a_n)_{n≥0}$ and $(b_n)_{n≥0}$ be two sequences of a nomed algebra such that $\sum{\| a_n\|}$ and $\sum{\| b_n\|}$ converge, and$ $$$\forall n, \  a_n, b_n \neq 0$$

Show that $(\forall  k \in \mathbb N^*,  \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}^k = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{b_n}^k) \implies \exists\ \sigma \in{\mathfrak S}_{\mathbb N} \ ,\ (a_n) = (b_{\sigma(n)})$

The vector-space should be a finite-dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector-space.

I do not see how to deal with the hypothesis. If you have ideas/hints...

It would be relevant to deal with complex sequences even if it is less general. But I don't think one can generalize using real and complex cases.

Comment: First you need to solve $a_1^k+a_2^k+a_3^k=b_1^k+b_2^k+b_3^k$ then they are equal after a permutation.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: But $a_1^k+a_2^k+a_3^k=b_1^k+b_2^k+b_3^k$ is not given, only the equality of the infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n^k = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n^k$.

Comment: Yeah , but just assume that all values beyond $a_2$ are zero, so this is an easier problem.

Comment: Oh, I see that you have this extra condition. Why ? How do you expect to solve this question if you cannot solve the simpler problem ?

Answer (score 5):

Assume without loss that $|b_i|\leq |b_0|$ for all $i>0$. 
You have 
$$\sum \left(\frac{a_i}{b_0}\right)^{2k}=\sum \left(\frac{b_i}{b_0}\right)^{2k}\to n$$

Where $n$ is the number of $b_i^2$'s equal to $b_0^2$.
Now let $k\to \infty$. The right hand side limits to $n$. The left hand side can go to $n$ if and only if for there are $n$, $i$'s such that $a_i^2=b_0^2$.

Now, to get the signs 
$$\sum \left(\frac{a_i}{b_0}\right)^{2k+1}=\sum \left(\frac{b_i}{b_0}\right)^{2k+1}$$ and both sides can have the same limits as $k\to \infty$ iff there are the same number of $1$,s as $-1$$'s.

Comment: Would you mind adding limits to the sums?

Comment: Why ? Is it so unclear ?

Comment: I tried a complex-analytic approach using $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n/(1 - a_n z)$ but this is much easier. (+1) If OP intended $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s to be complex, I guess that Cesaro mean may help.

Comment: Thank you . (+1) Yes @SangchulLee sequences can be complex.

Comment: It should be mentioned that some form of dominated convergence theorem is being used here, it interchange limits and sums.. The use of DCT is justified by the assumption of absolute summability of norms

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach which works for sequences in $\Bbb C$, obtained
by a small variation of Sangchul Lee's answer at [$a_n =0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ if $\sum a_n^k =0$ for all integers $k \ge 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433527/a-n-0-for-all-n-in-mathbb-n-if-sum-a-nk-0-for-all-integers-k-ge-1/1436048#1436048).

Assume that for some $w_0 \in \Bbb C$
$$ \tag{*}
 \# \{ j \mid a_j = w_0 \} \ne \# \{ j \mid b_j = w_0 \} \, .
$$ 
and set $z_0 = 1/w_0$.

Choose any $R > |z_0|$.
We have that $ |a_n|R \leq \frac{1}{2}$
and $ |b_n|R \leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all sufficiently large $n \ge N$,
and therefore
$$
 \left| \frac{a_n}{1 - a_n z} \right| \leq 2|a_n| \, , \quad \left| \frac{b_n}{1 - b_n z} \right| \leq 2|b_n| \, .
$$
for $|z| < R$ and $n \ge N$.
Then
$$
 f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \left( \frac{a_n}{1 - a_n z} - \frac{b_n}{1 - b_n z}\right) 
 + \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \left( \frac{a_n}{1 - a_n z} - \frac{b_n}{1 - b_n z}\right) 
$$
is well-defined in $B_R(0)$ as the sum of a rational function and a uniformly converging series of analytic functions, and a meromorphic
function in that disk (with at most finitely many poles).

Now $(*)$ implies that $f$ has a pole at $z_0$.
On the other hand,
$$
 \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n^{k+1} - b_n^{k+1}) = 0
$$
for each $k$, so that $f$ is identically zero, which is a contradiction.