Prove that a function is meromorphic

Prove that the following series define a meromorphic function in $\Bbb C$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sinh (n\pi z)}{n!(z^2+n)}$$
and find poles and function poles's order.


My attempt is the following, since
$$ \sinh (n\pi z) = \frac{e^{\pi n(x+iy)}-e^{-\pi n(x+iy)}}{2}$$
I think that
$$ |\sinh (n\pi z)|\leq \bigg (\frac{e^{\pi |x|}}{2}\bigg)^n$$
so I need
$$e^{\pi |x|} < 2 \iff |x| < \frac{\log 2}{\pi}$$
but if this is valid the region of convergence is $x \in \big(-\frac{\log 2}{\pi}, \frac{\log 2}{\pi}\big)$ and the function isn't meromorphic in $\Bbb C$. This led me to think that this argument is valid if $n!$ isn't in the denominator but I actually don't know how to prove it rigorously.
The part regarding function's pole we study the denominator and
$$(z^2+n)\neq 0\\
z\neq \pm i\sqrt n$$
each one is a 1-pole and I can easily evaluate the residue. Another thing I think I could say is that $\infty$ is not an isolated singularity because poles accumulates to infinity as $n$ increases. Thank you for your help and time!

Note that: for any $M>0$, the series $$\sum\frac{M^n}{n!}$$ is convergent.

$z^2+n^2$ in the denominator would seem more natural.

$$|\sinh (n\pi z) |\leq\frac{|e^{\pi n(x+iy)}|+|e^{-\pi n(x+iy)}|}{2}\leq\frac{e^{n\pi x}+e^{-n\pi x}}{z}\leq e^{n\pi|x|}.$$

My proof is similar to the proof in this post due to @Sangchul Lee(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433527/a-n-0-for-all-n-in-mathbb-n-if-sum-a-nk-0-for-all-integers-k-ge-1?noredirect=1), but here is a little hard than that.

We have  $$|\sinh (n\pi z)|\leq e^{n\pi|x|},\quad \sinh(\pi z)=0\iff z=ki,k=0,\pm1,\pm2,\cdots.$$
Take $D=\mathbb C\setminus\{\pm i\sqrt n\mid n=1,2,\cdots\}$, then $D$ is a domain. Take any compact subset $K$ of $D$, then there exist $\delta>0,R>0$, such that $$|z^2+n|\geq\delta>0,\quad |\sinh (n\pi z)\leq R^n,\quad \forall z\in K.$$
So when $z\in K$, we have
$$\left|\frac{\sinh (n\pi z)}{n!(z^2+n)}\right|
\leq\frac{R^n}{n!\cdot\delta},$$
since the series
$$\sum \frac{R^n}{n!\cdot\delta}$$
is convergent, so $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sinh (n\pi z)}{n!(z^2+n)}$$
converges umiformly on $K$, and Weierstrass's theorem implies that the sum function $$S(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sinh (n\pi z)}{n!(z^2+n)}$$
is holomorphic in the domain $D$.
On the other hand, when $k$ is not square, then $z_k=i\sqrt k$ are the simple poles of $S(z)$, because
$$\lim_{z\to z_k}S(z)
=\lim_{z\to z_k}\left(\frac{\sinh (k\pi z)}{k!(z^2+k)}+\sum_{n\neq k}^\infty\frac{\sinh (n\pi z)}{n!(z^2+n)}\right)
=\infty+\sum_{n\neq k}^\infty\frac{\sinh (n\pi z_k)}{n!(z_k^2+n)}
=\infty,$$
and
$$\lim_{z\to z_k}(z-z_k)S(z)=\frac{\sinh (k\pi z_k)}{k!(2i\sqrt k)}.$$
In the same way, when $k$ is not a square,  $-z_k$ are also the simple poles of $S(z)$.
Hence, $S(z)$ is  a meromorphic function in $\mathbb C$, the poles are $\pm i\sqrt k$, where $k$ is not a square, and all the poles are simple poles.

Why would you go on discuss if $z_k$ is a square or not? In my mind it's either way a pure imaginary number and I don't think that this could lead to some difference relatively to $k$, the rest is very clear!

I think I got it, we have to check that numerator and denominator do not vanish on the same values in order to have a pole, but this do not seems to happen for any value of $k\neq 0,1$ am I right? Are you sure about the zero of the numerator, is $\sinh$ periodic?

@Turquoise Tilt For fixed $n$, the numerator $$\sinh(n\pi z)=0\iff e^{n\pi z}=e^{-n\pi z}\iff e^{2n\pi z}=1\iff 2n\pi z=2m\pi i \iff z=\frac{m}{n}i, m\in\mathbb Z.$$  There are infinity many zeros for $\sinh(n \pi z)$, when choose $m=nk$, then $z=k i$. The common zeros of the numerator and denominator are only those cases.

$\sinh(z)$ is not periodic, but $e^z$ is periodic, i.e. $$e^{z+2m\pi i}=e^z,\quad \forall z\in\mathbb C,m\in\mathbb Z.$$
